# In-path executables not found when called from "Open command window here" console

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I uses several CLI tools such as `curl`, `ipcalc`, `perl`, `php`, `wget`, etc.

When opening a command prompt either via the Start menu or "Run..." > `cmd` I can invoke theses tools just by giving their name:

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\cduv>wget
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.

C:\Users\cduv>php
^C
```

But I've noticed that when using a command prompt opened via the native "Open command window here" entry of the SHIFT-down contextual menu it doesn't works.

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\cduv>wget
'wget' not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\cduv>php
'php' not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

PATH environment variable seems OK (otherwise I couldn't run executables as shown in the first example).

Is there an explanation to such a difference? How can I fix the "Open command window here" console?

(I'm using Windows 7)

EDIT:

%PATH% content on standard console:

```
C:\Users\cduv>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\ActivePerl 5.14.2.1402\site\bin;C:\Program Files\ActivePerl 5.14.2.1402\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP 5.5.5\ext;C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP 5.5.5;C:\Program Files (x86)\PsTools 2.44;C:\Program Files (x86)\wget 1.11.4;C:\Program Files\cURL 7.23.1;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit 1.7.15.0\bin;C:\Drivers\AMD Catalyst Suite 13.1\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Slik Subversion 1.8.3-1\bin
```

%PATH% content on "Open command window here" console:

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\ActivePerl 5.14.2.1402\site\bin;C:\Program Files\ActivePerl 5.14.2.1402\bin;%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PHP 5.5.5\ext;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PHP 5.5.5;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PsTools 2.44;%ProgramFiles(x86)%\wget 1.11.4;%ProgramFiles%\cURL 7.23.1;%ProgramFiles%\TortoiseGit 1.7.15.0\bin;C:\Drivers\AMD Catalyst Suite 13.1\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;%ProgramFiles%\Slik Subversion 1.8.3-1\bin
```

By using Process Explorer (from Sysinternals) I can tell which command line were used to open command prompt

- Via Start menu or Run prompt: `"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"`

  (Parent tree: explorer.exe > cmd.exe)
- Via "Open command window here": `"cmd.exe" /s /k pushd "C:\"`

  (Parent tree: wininit.exe > services.exe > svchost.exe > explorer.exe > cmd.exe)

Comment: whats the output of 'echo %path%' in your open cmdwndw here?

Comment: I can confirm that exes on my %PATH% are not affected by how I open the command prompt. I can execute them with no problem, both from `run -> cmd.exe` and from `open Command prompt here`.

Comment: If `wget` &c. aren't in any directory that's a member of your path, how are you executing them even in the successful case? Put it this way: If you don't edit your question to show the output of `echo %PATH%` for shells started both ways, no one who tries to answer your question is going to be able to get past thinking "Well, the paths must be different *somehow*...", so adding that information greatly increases your chances of getting a helpful answer, without any corresponding drawback. May as well go ahead and do it, don't you think?

Comment: I've added both %PATH% as correctly suggested. If we compare them they look almost the same except the "Open command window here" version display environment variables as such and not their value ( (id. `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)` as in the (working) standard console).

Comment: @CDuv The "open command window here" version not expanding environment variables seems rather likely to be at the root of the problem. I don't really know what you can do about that, but [this Super User question](http://superuser.com/q/27826/162434) and its answers look like they might make a good place to start.

Comment: How long has this been happening? Have you changed *any* environment variables recently (i.e., since the last time you rebooted)?