# Avoid alphabetical reading of Windows environment variables

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables

Normally, if I define one *User* Windows 10 environment variable (var 1) in terms of another (var 2), var 2 should precede var 1 in alphabetical order for it to work.
This is identified [here](https://superuser.com/a/823802/245595), e.g.

For instance, in the window

[image]

this

```
APYTHONDIR  ->  C:\Users\user1\myprogs
PATH  ->  %APYTHONDIR%
```

works, but this

```
PYTHONDIR  ->  C:\Users\user1\myprogs
PATH  ->  %PYTHONDIR%
```

does not.

**Is there any way of avoiding it?**
**Working around it?**

**I mean to get a solution that functionally works the same as if the variables were defined via registry (or Control Panel).**

I can always use naming to ensure "nested" definitions follow alphabetical order.
This is not what I want.

I thought about setting them in the desired order in a startup batch file (`autoexec.nt`, or whatever is current).
I am not sure if this would work for any application requiring the environment variables.
E.g., octave symbolic integration needing to find `python` somewhere in the `PATH`, with the directory in the `PATH` being added in this way.

**EDIT** As per the answers by harrymc and myself, and following discussion, this is what I tried:

1. Creating a file `set_env_vars.bat` in an arbitrary directory, and set a shortcut to it in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.
2. Adding a line `set /P PTEST=Enter value for PTEST` in `set_env_vars.bat` to make sure the file is being read during logon.
3. Logging off and on. I verified that `set_env_vars.bat` is read.

Then, I added lines

```
set ZTEST_DIR=C:\ztest
set YTEST_DIR=%ZTEST_DIR%;C:\ytest
```

to `set_env_vars.bat`.
Plus log off / log on. 
This didn't give me vars `ZTEST_DIR` and `YTEST_DIR` in my environment.

Then, I replaced those with lines

```
setx ZTEST_DIR C:\ztest
set /P WAITING_DUMMY=Enter value for WAITING_DUMMY   
setx YTEST_DIR %ZTEST_DIR%;C:\ytest
```

in `set_env_vars.bat`. 
(The second line to try giving time to the system to set the first var).
Plus log off / log on. 
This gave me vars

```
YTEST_DIR=;C:\ytest
ZTEST_DIR=C:\ztest
```

in my environment.

Comment: `autoexec.bat` was used with MS-DOS, Windows 3.x and Windows 95. It no longer exists since Windows NT.

Comment: Note also that alphabetical order is not needed for it to work. Test and see.

Comment: @harrymc - I am posting because that is what I observed.
And the link provided states the same.
Do you not see such behaviour?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Your question is unclear.  Why does the order of the environment variables matter?

Comment: @LawrenceC - I cannot figure out how to make the question any clearer... that is *what* I want to do.

As for *why* I want to do that: I mean to have uniform naming of several variables across Win and Linux systems. In the latter, defining one environment variable in terms of another (e.g., in `.bashrc`) is irrespective of alphabetical order; it depends on the order of execution of variables definition commands. The question shows that this is not that simple to achieve in Win.

I can always use naming to ensure "nested" definitions follow alphabetical order.
This is not what I want.

Comment: If I understand comments under the linked answer right, they say that you should define variables in the registry in the desired order and never use the control panel dialog, because it's the dialog what enforces alphabetical order by rearranging entries in the registry.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I did not understand it that way, but after your comment I tried it and it worked. I posted a summarizing answer accordingly.
Still, it has a pitfall, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary:

1. Setup file `setvars.cmd` (the name is arbitrary) in directory `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, or put `setvars.cmd` elsewhere and set a shortcut to it from there.
2. In that file, use (e.g.)

   ```
   setx DIR2 C:\dir2
   set DIR2=C:\dir2
   setx DIR1 %DIR2%;C:\dir1
   set DIR1=%DIR2%;C:\dir1
   ```

Tested and it works.
**If the Control Panel is ever used for setting *any* variables from this point on, it can mess up nested definitions that do not follow alphabetical order**.

---

**tl;dr**

There seem to be at least 3 alternative ways to define user environment variables:

1. Via Control Panel.

   Right-click computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> New for User variables for USER1 -> Type in *Name* and *Value* for the variable -> Ok.

   "Nested" usage of variables **is read in alphabetical order**.

   Variables are also displayed in alphabetical order.
2. Via registry editing of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`.

   Windows key -> reged -> Goto `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` in the address bar -> Edit -> New -> `REG_EXPAND_SZ` -> Type *Name* -> Right click on added name -> Modify -> Type *Value* -> Ok.

   "Nested" usage of variables **is read in the order they were defined**.

   Variables are displayed in alphabetical order, only for convenience.

   This answers the question, in principle. But if "nested" definitions that do not follow alphabetical order were used, one is "banned" from using the Control Panel method ever again, otherwise it enforces alphabetical order reading and messes up the definitions.
3. Via command line / batch file / autoexec.

   As detailed below.
   Helped by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1466289/245595), with the added use of [`SETX var value`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) instead of only [`SET var=value`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

   "Nested" usage of variables **is read in the order they were defined**.

   And with proper automation, this is done at each logon, so using the Control Panel way would only possibly mess up "nested" definitions for the current session. **This method is probably the best combination**.

Note that to avoid having to log off to reread variables, one can use [this](https://serverfault.com/a/489539/326962), or [`refreshenv`](https://pastebin.com/1fJqA0pT).

**Detail of method 3**:
The proper way of achieving the objective of the OP (get a solution that functionally works the same as if the variables were defined via registry (or Control Panel), but avoiding alphabetical ordering) is:

1. Using a `.bat` [(or, better, a `.cmd`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd) file, read during logon (method 3), say, `setvars.cmd`.
2. In that file, using `setx` to set environment variables at the registry level (e.g., `var2`).
   *This does not update the local environment*.
3. To be able to use "nested" variable definitions that endure for the windows session (e.g., `var1` in terms of the value of `var2`), one needs `var2` to be also defined in the process spawned by `setvars.cmd`. According to item 2 above, this is not accomplished by `setx`.
   For that, one would add a `set` line corresponding to each `setx` line.
   With this, the same environment is obtained in the registry and in the local process.
   Alternatively, one may try using `REG query HKCU\Environment /V ...` chained with other commands (as used, e.g., in [`refreshenv`](https://pastebin.com/1fJqA0pT)), but I did not pursue this.
   If the Control Panel way is ever used, it can mess up nested definitions that do not follow alphabetical order. This can be overcome by simply executing again `setvars.cmd`.

Comment: Method 1 only displays in alphabetical order for readability. Method 2&3 are the same in effect for setx. Set only works on local environment so doesn't relate.

Comment: @harrymc - I did not get whether you mean the proposed solution works or not.
Plus, as commented before, method 1 displays in alphabetical order, and applies settings in alphabetical order as well. That is what I see, and what others reported as well. I wouldn't know if your system behaves differently, and in that case what produces the difference.
Method 2 displays in alphabetical order, and applies settings in the order definitions were set.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `set "a=x%b%y"`, then `a` is defined exactly like that, and `%b%` will
only be expanded when required. This is why alphabetical order has no importance.
Variables are substituted when their value is required, and `PATH` is an example
of a value that is immediately required.

To automate setting environment variables, put the
[SET commands](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
in a batch file (`.bat`) and copy the file to the
[Startup folder](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2944-add-delete-enable-disable-startup-items-windows-10-a.html).

Your personal startup folder should be
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`, while the
*All Users* startup folder should be
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Question: What am I doing below that is different than what you do?
You could show us a similar screenshot if you are getting different results.

[image]

---

As regarding the example you have posted, the results are as expected.
You have used the `setx` command, which sets environment variables for the
user in the registry, *but not in the local environment*.
You would need to start a new Command Prompt from the desktop
to benefit from that variable.

The important point here is that `setx` works on the registry, but that
does not cause the local environment to be re-evaluated.
The environment is built only once, when a process is launched,
then stays the same all through execution (unless modified locally by
the process itself).
Any child started by a parent process will inherit its parent's environment,
so no reference is made in that case to the registry.

The demo below demonstrates the problem: The variable is set in the above
Command Prompt, but doesn't have a local value. The lower Command Prompt is then
started from the desktop, and it does have that value.

[image]

Comment: I have posted an answer. With reference to it, I was using method 1; you propose method 3, which is per se not sufficient (the automated definition is missing).
Besides, I do not know the difference, if any, when using quotes or not, in `set` commands.

Comment: Quotes in [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) are usually optional, but without them one may encounter weird effects in batch files. I have added a part about automation.

Comment: @sancho.s: Is for you my answer is now complete?

Comment: Maybe, I still didn't have time to try it. Will do it before the bounty expires.

Comment: It did not work. I posted what I tried as an edit to the OP, it wouldn't fit in a comment.
You may try it yourself, I bet you find an answer!

Comment: That's to be expected. I added a second part in my answer to explain the reason.

Comment: I think I have answered all questions by now.

Comment: As I understand it, you have explained why your proposal (or what I tested) do not work for the objective of the OP. But it does not provide a way for doing it.
I put everything together in an answer... please check it and comment if you fell like. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to correct the misconceptions, but apparently failed. Everything works when understood correctly as described above.

Comment: (I think) you made your points clear. What I did not see is specifically what solution you proposed to deal with the question.
From what I could understand from your answer (which runs along the lines proposed in the OP), I tested using `set`. That certainly did not solve the issue in the OP.
Nevertheless, it helped me coming up with my answer. That is why I upvoted, and I meant to award this half the bounty (currently, not possible).

Comment: No solution is required, things work as they should. All I can suggest is to read my answer again.

Comment: Harry, to be clear, I did what you suggest (I read it again, also), and it does not produce the intended result (as stated in the OP). At least in my system, and apparently in others' as well. I wonder whether it does produce the intended result in your system.
Please see my answer, where I explain in detail what works and what does not.
I think this may mislead others in SU.