# Escaping forward slash / in windows envrironment variable

Tags: windows, environment-variables, make

In a makefile, I want to use an environment variable `${PROJECT_SOURCE}` with value `/c/foo`.

But when I set my Windows 10 environment variable through control panel to `/c/foo`, the result is `C:\foo` when I execute my `make` command in `Mingw32`.
I need exactly `/c/foo`. I tried to escape with `^` or `%` when setting the variable in the control panel, but nothing works : it's stil `C:\foo` in `Mingw32` or `windows powershell`
I'm using a portable version of `Make 3.82.90`

example of command :

```
dos2unix:
      find ${PROJECT_SOURCE}/www/project/ -type f -name *.php | xargs dos2unix /
```

Comment: Please specify better your problem. Help others help you.
State: 
1) How do you set your Windows environment variable. There is more than one method.
2) Where do you see that "the result is C:\foo".
3) Where did you try what you tried.
4) How did you install make, and which version.
5) How are you using make.

Comment: @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio thank you kind sir

Comment: So the problem is not with make... You set an environment variable and Windows itself (e.g., in a Powershell prompt) "converts" it, correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear the exact problem you have, but I will attempt a solution.

Given that you mean to use `make` under `mingw32`, you could start setting up the variable in `mingw32` `bash`, instead of Control Panel.
This is what I tried in my msys2

```
$ export TEST="/c/Datos"
$ echo ${TEST}
```

So it doesn't get automatically converted to `C:\Datos`.
I am not sure if `make` will work later on, since there is still missing info.
If this works, you can make it persistent by adding to `~/.bashrc`

If setting up the variable in Control Panel is absolutely mandatory for you, this can at least help you identifying the problem and how to continue.
I cannot test the Control Panel way because of [this](https://superuser.com/a/1466418/245595).

Show:

1. The makefile which is giving problems.
   If it is too large, you may do some work to come up with a simpler "distilled case" (a MCVE) that reproduces the problem.
2. How you created the makefile.
3. The environment just prior to executing `make`. In particular, the value of the troublesome variable.

Comment: Thank you ! I just had to export the env variable with Mingw.
I don't know if this will be persisted and available after reboot, tho. if not, I will add it in mingw `.bashrc`