# Reuse of environment variables in Path

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, powershell, environment-variables

Is it possible to reuse environment variables in the Path environment variable from PowerShell?

There are some environment variables like `%SystemRoot%` defined and are used in Path variable `...;%SystemRoot%\system32;...` viewed in the Advanced System Settings.

In PowerShell these are defined as `$Env:SystemRoot` and `$Env:Path` part of that path is resolved with `...;c:\windows\system32;...`

How to create and use such a custom variable in the Path? e.g. `$Env:MyPath = 'c:\mypath'` adding it to Path like `...;%MyPath%\documents;...` and get the same effect in both Advanced System Settings and PowerShell `$Env:Path` resolution?

Answer (score 4):

### My god, it's full of variables

There is [three types of environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx):

1. Machine

   > The environment variable is stored or retrieved from the
   > **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session
   > Manager\Environment** key in the Windows operating system registry. When
   > a user creates the environment variable in a set operation, the
   > operating system stores the environment variable in the system
   > registry, but not in the current process. **If any user on the local
   > machine starts a new process, the operating system copies the
   > environment variable from the registry to that process.** When the
   > process terminates, the operating system destroys the environment
   > variable in that process. However, **the environment variable in the
   > registry persists until a user removes it programmatically or by means
   > of an operating system tool.**
2. User

   > The environment variable is stored or retrieved from the
   > **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment** key in the Windows operating system
   > registry. When the user creates the environment variable in a set
   > operation, the operating system stores the environment variable in the
   > system registry, but not in the current process. If the user starts a
   > new process, the operating system copies the environment variable from
   > the registry to that process. When the process terminates, the
   > operating system destroys the environment variable in that process.
   > However, the environment variable in the registry persists until the
   > user removes it programmatically or by means of an operating system
   > tool.
3. Process

   > The environment variable is stored or retrieved from the environment
   > block associated with the current process. The user creates the
   > environment variable in a set operation. When the process terminates,
   > the operating system destroys the environment variable in that
   > process.

Newly created with `$env:` environment variables in PowerShell are of `Process` type. For variable to display in the `Advanced System Settings` it has be the `Machine` or `User` level variable. To create variable with specific level use [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) method:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MyPath', 'c:\mypath', 'User')

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MyPath', 'c:\mypath', 'Machine')
```

Note, that setting `Machine` level environment variables requires elevation.

### Do you read me, HAL?

So you want to embed one environment variable inside another and have it expanded? After all, Microsoft does it all the way, for example per user `TEMP` and `TMP` variables  contain `USERPROFILE` env.var. Unfortunately,  there is a number of quirks attached:

1. The underlying registry entry for such variable [has to be](https://superuser.com/a/484101/418201) `REG_EXPAND_SZ type`
2. The containee env. variable has to be [alphabetically less](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_install/how-to-use-programfiles-in-the-path-environment/48b23109-9fbc-47c5-a5d1-465773f94704) than container env. variable:

   > If the definition of an environment variable **var1** contains another
   > environment variable **var2** and the name of **var1** is alphabetically less
   > than the name of **var2** (i.e. **strcmp(var1, var2) < 0**), then **var2** won't
   > get expanded. This seems to be because when Windows first sets up the
   > environment variables, they are created in alphabetical order, so **var2**
   > does not exist until after var1 has already been created (and so the
   > expansion can't be done).
3. For `PATH` variable, there should be [no spaces between entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13030697/4424236):

   Incorrect: `c:\path1; c:\Maven\bin\; c:\path2\`
   Correct: `c:\path1;c:\Maven\bin\;c:\path2\`

Furthermore, if you try to make use of [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes.aspx) method like this:

```
$Path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine')
    
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MyPath', 'c:\mypath', 'Machine')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', "%MyPath%;$Path", 'Machine')
```

It will not yield to a desired result, because a newly created `PATH` variable will not have have type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, but `REG_SZ`.

### Open the pod bay doors, HAL

Given that `SetEnvironmentVariable` has no means to control resulting registry entry type, you have to employ alternative: [directly modify registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295260/4424236) to create an entry of the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type.

```powershell
$Path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','Machine')

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('MyPath', 'c:\mypath', 'Machine')

[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue(
    'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment',
    'Path',
    "%MyPath%;$Path",
    [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString
)
```

The disadvantages of this method is that it doesn't [broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message](http://web.archive.org/web/20150226120440/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011) to all windows in the system, so that any interested applications (such as Windows Explorer, Program Manager, Task Manager, Control Panel, and so forth) can perform an update.

To mitigate that, you can [broadcast message](https://web.archive.org/web/20161215010124/http://poshcode.org/2049) yourself:

```powershell
if (-not ('Win32.NativeMethods' -as [type])) {
    # import SendMessageTimeout from Win32
    Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name NativeMethods -MemberDefinition @'

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(
            IntPtr hWnd,
            uint Msg,
            UIntPtr wParam,
            string lParam,
            uint fuFlags,
            uint uTimeout,
            out UIntPtr lpdwResult);
'@
}

$HWND_BROADCAST = [System.IntPtr]0xffff
$WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a
$result = [System.UIntPtr]::Zero

# Notify all windows of environment block change
[Win32.NativeMethods]::SendMessageTimeout(
    $HWND_BROADCAST, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
    [System.UIntPtr]::Zero,
    'Environment',
    2,
    5000,
    [ref]$result
)
```

Comment: thank you for extensive comment, is it possible to reuse one variable inside some part of one of the paths in $Env:Path?

Comment: Yes, but some assembly required, See update.

Comment: OMGoodness, TY.