# Windows 10 environment paths

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

I have installed Gradle manually & setup envirnment variable GRADLE_HOME = C:/gradle and set the environment path to %GRADLE_HOME%/bin.

Everything works after I press Ok but its not recorgnized after restart my computer.

Update: this works fine when I add the whole path to PATH and exclude my custom variable

I have tried to compare with other paths and searched the net, no luck

How can I fix this? & please explain whats going on.

Comment: Have you added the path using %PATH% in CMD? Or by using Environment Variables dialog under System Properties? Are you on a domain which rolls out group policy updates?

Comment: I am using the Environment Variable Dailog. I hv done this b4 for java and it works fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Windows handle an environment variable in Path?](https://superuser.com/questions/27826/why-cant-windows-handle-an-environment-variable-in-path)